# How to autoscroll tableview when a new item added to it?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, ios4

How to autoscroll tableview when a new item is added to it?

I tred to use

```
- (void)scrollToRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
              atScrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition 
                      animated:(BOOL)animated
```

But I couldn't figure it out.

Can you please provide sample code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For better guidance, you should see the docs for [[UITableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:]](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW7)

Below is the instant solution....

```
int row = [dataController count] - 1;
int section = 0;
NSIndexPath *scrollIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section];
[[self tableView] scrollToRowAtIndexPath:scrollIndexPath
                        atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom 
                                animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to your code from where you wants to scroll tableview.

```
[myTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[_databaseArray count]-1 inSection:0]
                   atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom
                           animated:YES];
```

Comment: Please add some description to your answer to allow us mortals to understand the solution you provide.